# Clojure: unable to import specific methods from java class

Tags: java, clojure, smile

Possible linked to [Cannot call particular java method from Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968216/cannot-call-particular-java-method-from-clojure)

Using the smile package, I've upgraded to 3.0.0 and failing to call some methods. My Leiningen project.clj has the following import `[com.github.haifengl/smile-core "3.0.0"]`

Now in the REPL:

```
(import smile.math.MathEx)

(MathEx/log2 5.)
=> 2.321928094887362
(MathEx/pow2 5.)
Syntax error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling . at (C:\Users\AAlmosni\AppData\Local\Temp\1\form-init13649993705313983821.clj:1:1).
No matching method pow2 found taking 1 args for class smile.math.MathEx
(MathEx/sigmoid 5.)
Syntax error (IllegalArgumentException) compiling . at (C:\Users\AAlmosni\AppData\Local\Temp\1\form-init13649993705313983821.clj:1:1).
No matching method sigmoid found taking 1 args for class smile.math.MathEx
(MathEx/isPower2 32)
=> true
```

This is very confusing to me - some methods work fine, some don't. Here's an extract from MathEx.class:

```
    public static double log2(double x) {
        return Math.log(x) / LOG2;
    }

    public static double log(double x) {
        double y = -690.7755D;
        if (x > 1.0E-300D) {
            y = Math.log(x);
        }

        return y;
    }

    public static double log1pe(double x) {
        double y = x;
        if (x <= 15.0D) {
            y = Math.log1p(Math.exp(x));
        }

        return y;
    }

    public static boolean isInt(float x) {
        return x == (float)Math.floor((double)x) && !Float.isInfinite(x);
    }

    public static boolean isInt(double x) {
        return x == Math.floor(x) && !Double.isInfinite(x);
    }

    public static boolean equals(double a, double b) {
        if (a == b) {
            return true;
        } else {
            double absa = Math.abs(a);
            double absb = Math.abs(b);
            return Math.abs(a - b) <= Math.min(absa, absb) * 2.220446049250313E-16D;
        }
    }

    public static double sigmoid(double x) {
        x = Math.max(-36.0D, Math.min(x, 36.0D));
        return 1.0D / (1.0D + Math.exp(-x));
    }

    public static double pow2(double x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    public static boolean isPower2(int x) {
        return x > 0 && (x & x - 1) == 0;
    }
```

Any idea what is causing the failed imports?

Thanks,

Comment: It might be a version dependency conflict. E.g. the `pow2` function was called `sqr` before: https://github.com/haifengl/smile/commit/e81f2309ea7d653a7587808744c8b7a4b8886a3a Make sure you are using the right version of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Juraj was hinting it was a dependency conflict - I was also using `tech.ml.dataset` in my project, version 6, which was using an older version of `smile`. Moving `tech.ml.dataset` to version 7, which doesn't include `smile` by default, sorted the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer.